# Convert and hexadecimal string into a datetime result in python

Tags: python, hex

I have been trying to find a way to perform the following action.

I just received an excel file with the following formula.

```
  Row Value                   Excel formula                                               Result
 608332e6943e7263a56fb3ff   =(((HEX2DEC(LEFT("row value",8))/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)   4/23/2021  8:49:42 PM
```

I wondering if there is a way for me to achieve this same result in python. I tried the following but it did not work.

```
df_final = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")
print(df_final)

                    Card ID  # of Members Created Date
0  608332c0806da55df13b498b             2     608332c0
1  60819c7ccd3a695b79f54f53             5     60819c7c
2  60817b9df8f5422bbaf2cff9             9     60817b9d
3  60806f3d24f11404f1470904             2     60806f3d
4  607ed78a89de73411e937655             1     607ed78a
5  608332e6943e7263a56fb3ff             2     608332e6
6               6.05364E+23             5     6.05364E
7               6.04084E+23             6     6.04084E
8               6.05395E+22             2     6.05395E
9               6.04716E+23             1     6.04716E

hexa = df_final["Created Date"]
df_final["Created Date"] = ((int(hexa,16)/60)/60)/24 + datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)
print(df_final)
```

I am looking to get an output like this:

```
                        Card ID  # of Members Created Date
0  608332c0806da55df13b498b             2     4/23/2021
1  60819c7ccd3a695b79f54f53             5     4/22/2021
2  60817b9df8f5422bbaf2cff9             9     4/22/2021
3  60806f3d24f11404f1470904             2     4/21/2021
4  607ed78a89de73411e937655             1     4/20/2021
5  608332e6943e7263a56fb3ff             2     4/23/2021
6               6.05364E+23             5     Invalid
7               6.04084E+23             6     Invalid
8               6.05395E+22             2     Invalid
9               6.04716E+23             1     Invalid
```

However, all I am getting is the following error:

```
df_final["Created Date"] = ((int(hexa,16)/60)/60)/24 + datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

Thoughts about how to get this done?
I appreciate any help!
Joe.

---

Based on Otávio's response, I try to re-run but I am still not able to achieve what I am looking for.

While the exercise get the work done if there is just one string, it is not getting the job done when it comes multiple values. Here is the example:

```
df_final = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")
df_final["Created Date"] = df_final["Card ID"].str[0:8]
print(df_final)
hex = df_final["Created Date"]
dtime_obj = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(hex, 16))
datetime_str = dtime_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')

print(df_final)

                        Card ID  # of Members Created Date
0  608332c0806da55df13b498b             2     608332c0
1  60819c7ccd3a695b79f54f53             5     60819c7c
2  60817b9df8f5422bbaf2cff9             9     60817b9d
3  60806f3d24f11404f1470904             2     60806f3d
4  607ed78a89de73411e937655             1     607ed78a
5  608332e6943e7263a56fb3ff             2     608332e6
6               6.05364E+23             5     6.05364E
7               6.04084E+23             6     6.04084E
8               6.05395E+22             2     6.05395E
9               6.04716E+23             1     6.04716E
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\JUB\Desktop\Manual Formulas 1\hexa.py", line 16, in <module>
    dtime_obj = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(hex, 16))
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

Thank you guys for helping me out!
Joe.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the hex string to an int, then this int to a datetime tuple:

```
import datetime
hex = '608332c0'
dtime_obj = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(hex, 16))
datetime_str = dtime_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M') # '2021-04-23T20:49:04Z'
```

Comment: Hi Otávio, thanks for taking the time to look into it. I have added more context to the problem cause that piece of code above gets the job done with one string only. So I am wondering a way to get the job done using the entire values of the column "created date"

Comment: Loop over the csv rows, set the value of the 'hex' variable value [2] in the array (the one correspondent to the Created Date) and the code is basically the same.

Comment: Thanks Otávio, I will try that. In the meantime, are you familiar with an alternative method to get the same work done using an embedded function either in pandas or numpy? I'm trying to optimize the execution time.

Comment: Sorry, don't know, not a data science guy! Can you please upvote my answers if I have helped you solve the issue?